# How to parse Rust code without using procedural macros?

Tags: parsing, rust

I am writing an analyzer which needs an abstract syntax tree (AST) or control flow graph (CFG) of Rust code. It seems impossible for me to do this without implementing a parser by myself.

I've noticed some crates such as `syn` and `quote`, but they don't work without using procedural macros and creating a totally unnecessary project structure. I've found that there's a crate called `syntex_syntax` which meets my requirements, but it is no longer maintained and panics when some code with newer syntax is given.

Is there any way of parsing Rust code directly: read from an arbitrary external *.rs file and parse it using `syn` or `quote` just like `syntex_syntax` did?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`syn` is a Rust parser and is not only for procedural macros. Take a look at [the "functions" section of the documentation](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.43/syn/#functions). There you will find these functions (as of syn 0.15):

- `fn parse<T: Parse>(tokens: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> Result<T>`: this is what you would use in a procedural macro.
- `fn parse2<T: Parse>(tokens: proc_macro2::TokenStream) -> Result<T>`: the same, but with the `TokenStream` from the `proc_macro2` crate.
- `fn parse_str<T: Parse>(s: &str) -> Result<T>`: parsing from a simple string. No `TokenStream`s required.
- `fn parse_file(content: &str) -> Result<File>`: Very similar to `parse_str`, but some convenient differences. See [docs for more information](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.43/syn/fn.parse_file.html).

**You can use `parse_str` or `parse_file` to parse Rust code from outside of procedural macros.**

A few additional notes:

- `quote` is not needed in your case. This crate is just used to easily create `TokenStream`s; it's not required for parsing.
- In case you are just interested in parsing the tokens, you can use `proc_macro2` outside of a procedural macro, too!
- `syntex_syntax` is indeed deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Just thinking about how it was used makes me shudder :P